# php calendar: adding days of week from previous month to first week

Tags: php, calendar

I have a calendar that I made with php. It looks like this:

[image: Calendar]

The image above is of the month March. It looks fine, but when I choose August it looks like this:

[image: Calendar of August that is bad]

(the two numbers in each box are: top one: day. bottom one: another number that i put in that doesn't mean anything)

If you notice on the right side for day one, it is not even on the calendar.

How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$date = time() ;

$day = date('d', $date) ;
$month = date('m', $date);
$year = date('Y', $date);

$first_day = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year) ;

$title = date('F', $first_day) ;

$day_of_week = date('D', $first_day) ;
switch($day_of_week){ 
case "Sun": $blank = 0; break; 
case "Mon": $blank = 1; break; 
case "Tue": $blank = 2; break; 
case "Wed": $blank = 3; break; 
case "Thu": $blank = 4; break; 
case "Fri": $blank = 5; break; 
case "Sat": $blank = 6; break; 
 } 

$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year) ;

echo "<table border=1 width=294>"; 
echo "<tr><th colspan=7> $title $year </th></tr>"; 
echo "<tr><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>M</td><td width=42>T</td><td     width=42>W</td><td width=42>T</td><td width=42>F</td><td width=42>S</td></tr>";            //This counts the days in the week, up to 7 
$day_count = 1; echo "<tr>"; 



if($month-1 != 0) {
$last_month = $month-1;
}
else {
$last_month = 12;
}
if($last_month == '12') {
$year = $year-1;
}
$last_month_first_day = mktime(0,0,0,$last_month, 1, $year);
$last_month_days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $last_month, $year);
$last_month_day_of_week = date('D', $last_mont_days_in_month);
$last_month_days_to_add_to_last_month_end = $blank++;
$last_month_end = $last_month_days_in_month-    $last_month_days_to_add_to_last_month_end;



while ( $blank > 0 ) { 

echo "<td><span style='color:grey'>" . $last_month_end . "</span></td>"; 
$last_month_end++;
$blank = $blank-1; 
$day_count++; 
}

$day_num = 1; 

while ( $day_num <= $days_in_month ) { 
echo "<td><a href='/test/day.php?day=" . $day_num . "&month=" . $title . "&year=" . $year . "'>" . $day_num . '<br>';
echo "</a></td>"; 
$day_num++;
$day_count++; 

if ($day_count > 7) { 
echo "</tr><tr>"; 
$day_count = 1; 
} 
}

$end_days = 1;
while ( $day_count >1 && $day_count <=7 )   {   
echo "<td><span style='color:grey;'>" . $end_days . "</span></td>";   
$day_count++;   
$end_days++;
}   
echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```

or is there a better way to add the end of the last month to the beginning of the new calendar? and the same for the next month to the end of this calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the line

```
$last_month_days_to_add_to_last_month_end = $blank++;
```

to

```
$last_month_days_to_add_to_last_month_end = $blank;
```

Comment: That changed the result but didn't get the result I wanted. the days are shifted out of place.

Comment: Just tested your code and found another "bug" @phprunner

Comment: Thanks. I will change it right now and test it. (and i apologize for my really long variable names... i was bored last night)

Comment: So when I changed it from `$last_......end = $blank++;` to `$last_....end=$blank;` with the switch change that you made. It was still messed up. I tried changing the switch back to `case "Sun": $blank = 0` and `case "Sat": $blank = 6;` and it works now. all the days are in the right order and on the right day of week. So if you change your answer to making the `switch()` back I will mark you as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$date = time() ;

$day = date('d', $date) ;
$month = date('m', $date);
$year = date('Y', $date);

$first_day = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year) ;

$title = date('F', $first_day) ;

$day_of_week = date('D', $first_day) ;
switch($day_of_week){ 
case "Sun": $blank = 0; break; 
case "Mon": $blank = 1; break; 
case "Tue": $blank = 2; break; 
case "Wed": $blank = 3; break; 
case "Thu": $blank = 4; break; 
case "Fri": $blank = 5; break; 
case "Sat": $blank = 6; break; 
 } 





if($month-1 != 0) {
$last_month = $month-1;
}
else {
$last_month = 12;
}
if($last_month == '12') {
$year = $year-1;
}
$last_month_first_day = mktime(0,0,0,$last_month, 1, $year);
$last_month_days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $last_month, $year);
$last_month_day_of_week = date('D', $last_mont_days_in_month);
$last_month_days_to_add_to_last_month_end = $blank;
$last_month_end = $last_month_days_in_month-    $last_month_days_to_add_to_last_month_end;




$days_in_month = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year) ;

echo "<table border=1 width=294>"; 
echo "<tr><th colspan=7> $title $year </th></tr>"; 
switch($blank){ 
case "0": echo "<tr><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>M</td><td width=42>T</td><td width=42>W</td><td width=42>T</td><td width=42>F</td><td width=42>S</td></tr>";  break; 
case "1": echo "<tr><td width=42>M</td><td width=42>T</td><td width=42>W</td><td width=42>T</td><td width=42>F</td><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>S</td></tr>"; break; 
case "2":  echo "<tr><td width=42>T</td><td width=42>W</td><td width=42>T</td><td width=42>F</td><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>M</td></tr>"; break; 
case "3":  echo "<tr><td width=42>W</td><td width=42>T</td><td width=42>F</td><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>M</td><td width=42>T</td></tr>"; break; 
case "4":  echo "<tr><td width=42>T</td><td width=42>F</td><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>M</td><td width=42>T</td><td width=42>W</td></tr>"; break; 
case "5": echo "<tr><td width=42>F</td><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>M</td><td width=42>T</td><td width=42>W</td><td width=42>T</td></tr>"; break; 
case "6": echo "<tr><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>M</td><td width=42>T</td><td     width=42>W</td><td width=42>T</td><td width=42>F</td></tr>";  break; 

default: echo "<tr><td width=42>S</td><td width=42>M</td><td width=42>T</td><td     width=42>W</td><td width=42>T</td><td width=42>F</td></tr>"; 
 } 

          //This counts the days in the week, up to 7 
$day_count = 1; echo "<tr>"; 





$day_num = 1; 

while ( $day_num <= $days_in_month ) { 
echo "<td><a href='/test/day.php?day=" . $day_num . "&month=" . $title . "&year=" . $year . "'>" . $day_num . '<br>';
echo "</a></td>"; 
$day_num++;
$day_count++; 

if ($day_count > 7) { 
echo "</tr><tr>"; 
$day_count = 1; 
} 
}

$end_days = 1;
while ( $day_count >1 && $day_count <=7 )   {   
echo "<td><span style='color:grey;'> - </span></td>";   
$day_count++;   
$end_days++;
}   
echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```